# I have a problem with urls in django, and I have "Page not found"

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I started to learn Django myself, and there is a problem with understanding how URLs and path work.

The error message is:

> Page not found (404)
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    `http://127.0.0.1:8000/question/1/`
> Using the URLconf defined in not_bad.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
> [name='index']
> [name='detail']
> [name='results']
> [name='vote']
> microsanya/
> The current path, question/1/, didn't match any of these.

**In project files I have this code:**

*not_bad\urls.py:*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('polls.urls')),
    path('microsanya/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

*polls/urls.py:*

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('', views.results, name='results'),
    path('', views.vote, name='vote' ),
]
```

*polls/views.py*

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404

from . models import Question, Choice


def index(request):
    question = Question.objects.all()
    return render(request, "index.html", {"latest_questions": Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]})


def detail(request, question_id):
    def detail(request, question_id):
      try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
      except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render(request, 'polls/answer.html', {'question': question})


def answer(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        question = question.question_set.get(pk=request.POST['question'])
    except (KeyError, Question.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'answer.html', {'question': question, 'error_message': 'Question does not exist'})
    else:
        if question.correct:
            return render(request, "index.html", {"latest_questions": Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5], "message": "Nice! Choose another one!"})
        else:
            return render(request, 'answer.html', {'question': question, 'error_message': 'Wrong Answer!'})

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

I have files named index.html and answer.html, but I don't think that the problem is situated in them.

Comment: You have to change the url patterns like so:    `path('question/<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),` etc. Check out the django docs for more examples: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: Currently PATTERNS are not defined in your url**patterns** config, so define them. Different pattern/template/regex for each **url pattern**. `question/<int:id>` for question details pages, `vote/<int:id>` or `question/int:id/vote` for voting and so on.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, I finally figured out how it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide paths in your `urlpatterns`.

For example:

<project_name>/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('question/', include('polls.urls')),
    # ...
]
```

polls/urls.py

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote' ),
]
```

In this example, all the paths for your app will begin in `/question/`, then the index (exact) path will be directed to `index` view, `/question/1/` to `detail` view and so on.

Comment: I tried it and it worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help anytime. Can you please mark it as "Accepted"?